# Is WG11 a device replacing MIPS or a theory no MIPS is needed?

Tags: helmets, terminology

If found some web talks of this, but these were so foggy and topic-jumping that I still cannot come to conclusion. What one of the two is true that Kask (helmet maker) actually wants to say:

- We have the alternative device or design features (which?) in our helmets that replaces the MIPS functionality.
- We have the alternative way of evaluation showing that MIPS is not needed (hair and skin provides enough protection).

They talk about the different heads used for the measurement, but this equipment is not part of the helmet itself. Is it the skepticism only or they have done something differently?

Kask says they helmets are not MIPS compliant but "WG11 compliant" instead.

Answer (score 5):

MIPS is not a standard, it's a brand that is linked to some technologies/patents for a specific use case (rotational impact) that helmets manufacturers can use (against a fee and an additional certification - probably like GoreTex for clothing).

If a manufacturer finds a way to cover this use case without infringing MIPS IP, they can sell the products, but obviously, they can't call it MIPS (and won't benefit from the brand recognition, that seems to be important to justify a premium).

Kask is not the only one to have their "brand" for this use case. I'm aware that Trek/Bontrager has WaveCel (they also sell MIPS helmets at higher price points, but as consumer, hard to say if this higher price is based on technical merit or the MIPS brand recognition), and probably other bike/helmet have their own technology as well.